# ACAccountStore not granted access

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm developing a Share Extension that will access the user's social networking accounts. I'm using the following to access the user's twitter account info:

```
    let accountStore = ACAccountStore()
    let accountType = accountStore.accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter)
    accountStore.requestAccessToAccountsWithType(accountType, options: nil, completion: { granted, error in
        if granted {
         // do stuff 
        } else {
         // report an error
        }
```

This works in the parent app for the extension but if I put that code into the window controller for the share window, The user is asked to grant access to their twitter accounts. Then, granted is set to false and I get an NSError object with a localized description of "Setting TCC failed".  What does that mean?

update: after a little more digging I learned that TCC.db is a database where privacy settings are stored. So, in this case, I'm presented with the dialog asking if I want to grant access, but there is an error for some reason in granting the access. I checked Console for sandboxd messages related to this but there are none.

Comment: If you're using El Capitan there is a known OS bug around this https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/issues/217